# Which footprint can identify in Virtualization?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

Think this example:
You are using Windows as a *host machine* and you are using ( virtualbox ) Linux for *virtual machine*. When you connect to the internet from virtual machine, someone try to track you. Now, can tracker find your host machine's footprint or just virtual machine's footprint? So, from the connection of virtual machine, the host machine can identifiable?

I try to search that but i can't find any result. Maybe i don't know the right words.

Answer (score 0):

No, the host machine won't be identifiable